# How to verify user authentication before viewing "View" in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

So I have a "dashboard" controller that points to the corresponding view. This file can be accessed at any time simply by going to `http://domain.com/dashboard`. However, I only want this URL to be accessed IF the user is logged in already. If not, they're redirected back to the home page.

So TWO part question:

1. How do I prevent a user from accessing the "dashboard" if they're not logged in first (should redirect to home page otherwise)...**EDIT: THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN FIXED AND CODE UPDATED BELOW**
2. On the register controller, instead of a user being directed to the `thank()` function (which brings them to a thank you for registering page), how do I log the user in automatically and take them to the dash?

Here's my "dashboard" controller. **Edit:** Now works as it should. Second (2) issue above still remains.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this -> load -> model('user_model');
}

public function index()
public function index()
{
    $session = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    if ($session == 1) 
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';
        $this -> load -> view('shared/header_view', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('dash', $data);
        $this -> load -> view('shared/footer_view', $data);
    }
    else {
        redirect('register');
    }
}
}
```

Here's my registration controller that logins, logouts, and registers the user:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Register extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this -> load -> model('user_model');
}

public function index() 
{
    if (($this -> session -> userdata('user_name') != "")) {
        $this -> welcome();
    } 
    else
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Home';
        $this -> load -> view('shared/header_view', $data);
        $this -> load -> view("registration_view.php", $data);
        $this -> load -> view('shared/footer_view', $data);
    }
}

public function welcome() 
{
     redirect('/dashboard/', 'refresh');
}

public function login() 
{
    $email = $this -> input -> post('email');
    $password = md5($this -> input -> post('pass'));

    $result = $this -> user_model -> login($email, $password);
    if ($result)
        $this -> welcome();
    else
        $this -> index();
}

public function thank() 
{
    $data['title'] = 'You are now registered!';
    $this -> load -> view('shared/header_view', $data);
    $this -> load -> view('thank_view.php', $data);
    $this -> load -> view('shared/footer_view', $data);
}

public function registration() 
{
    $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
    // field name, error message, validation rules
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('con_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) 
    {
        $this -> index();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this -> user_model -> add_user();
        $this -> thank();
    }
}

public function logout() 
{
    $newdata = array('user_id' => '', 'user_name' => '', 'user_email' => '', 'logged_in' => FALSE, );
    $this -> session -> unset_userdata($newdata);
    $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
    redirect('/', 'refresh');
}
```

}

EDIT: AS Requested, here's the user_model:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function login($email, $password) 
{
    $this -> db -> where("email", $email);
    $this -> db -> where("password", $password);

    $query = $this -> db -> get("user");
    if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $rows) 
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                'user_id' => $rows -> id,
                'user_name' => $rows -> username,
                'user_email' => $rows -> email,
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
            );
        }
        $this -> session -> set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function add_user() 
{
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this -> input -> post('user_name'),
        'email' => $this -> input -> post('email_address'),
        'password' => md5($this -> input -> post('password')),
    );
    $this -> db -> insert('user', $data);
}
```

}

Codeigniter newbie. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some...but some is also from a tutorial. Why do you ask mate?

Comment: Because you already done harder part and asking the easier ones. None the less, you aren't following a uniform manner to check whether the user is logged in or not. Some times it is zero, some times it is empty string....

Comment: Okay, are you able to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule on the dashboard controller looks a bit weird:

```
if ($session == 0)
```

Is the username really 0?? Or are you storing a boolean in this session. You should probably post your user_model too so we can see what you are doing there.

You should try to login a user and set a session like so:

```
$qry = $this->db->query("Select * from users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
if( $qry->num_results > 0 )
{
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('logged_in' => true);
    redirect('dashboard');
}
```

And When a user tries to go to the dashboard just perform a check like this:

```
if( !$this->session->userdate('logged_in') )
{
     redirect(base_url());
}
```

So when there is no session logged_in or the session is false => redirect.

You can do the same when registering a user. After the user was registered succesfull and added to the database, just create the session like you did on the login function and redirect to the dashboard.

Comment: Yeah, $session 0 shouldn't be there. Missed that. That was me mucking around. I had 1 there originally. I added the model... :)

Comment: Can you add some more info about what is exactly going wrong? certain errors you are getting or is the welcome method not redirecting on users that aren't logged in etc....

Comment: No errors. The first and main concern is the dashboard controller. If I go to domain.com/dashboard NOT logged in, I can access and see that page. I only want that page accessible IF they user have permission to view (i.e. he's logged in, etc.). Second, in the register controller, after the user registers, instead of the thank() function running and the user sees a "Thank You For Registering" page, I want them to be logged in and directed to the dashboard.

Comment: Okay, so I figured out the dashboard login check. Updated the code above. Now how do I sign in and redirect after registration?

Comment: After registration/correct submitted login-form. just create the session. Check out my second piece of code